# How can i navigate pages inside a page in Windows Phone Application

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

i am creating a WindowsPhone Application for which i have to navigate to some pages inside my app, but i dont want to leave the MainPage.

Its like a small page inside the MainPage, is there any way possible?

I tried creating User Control for the same, but the disadvantage is the User Control loads just after the MainPage is loaded, but i dont want the same. I want to click somewhere in my app then it loads the next page inside (keeping my application fast) instead of loading all user controls at once on MainPage load event.

If there is any alternative way you can help, please respond.

Comment: You can create a Popup which is a complete page. It will load quickly and disappear quickly.

Comment: sorry but i want it to be a navigation page, as for my task i have to use pivot or panorama, popup's wont help.

The Main thing is i am using animation in my MainPage, if i navigate to another page the animation will reset (bad for my app), so i have to navigate according to the events.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to navigate to a frame while first frame remains open. and as you cannot use popup due to pivot/panorama. you have to stick with the user control approach. you can optimize your xaml for performance below are some tips on how to optimize xaml

[Optimize loading XAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh994641.aspx)

**Edit**

```
    MyUserControl1 control = new MyUserControl1();
    control.DataContext = //bindable data from usercontrol
    this.ContentRoot.Children.Add(control);
```

Comment: thanx buddy for the reply, as i said If i use user control, i will have to create more than 10 user controls (required in my app), no problem in that.

But when the MainPage loads the user control is automatically loaded whithout calling them, so as having 10 user controls which contains a bulk of data (lets says 2000 songs), it will be very slow and inefficient.

As everything will be called when the app gets activated.
So, i am hoping for the better control than that, else have to optimize with user control :(

Comment: or else if there is a way to stop activating the user control when the parent page is loaded and activating/initializing it according to my need, it will work :)

Comment: What about dynamically adding user control using code behind? when ever it is needed. say on any tap event?

Comment: is there way to dynamically initialize user control (which will be having items like listbox - for adding some binded data)?

Comment: it is fairly simple to add user control dynamically and provide data. see my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

Just have a Frame inside your MainPage. Navigate to other pages using that frame.

```
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBlock Text="Title" />
                <Button Click="Button_Click"
                        Content="Page1"
                        Tag="SharedFrame.BasicPage1" />
                <Button Click="Button_Click"
                        Content="Page2"
                        Tag="SharedFrame.BasicPage2" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1">
            <Frame x:Name="rootFrame" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

This is how you navigate from the code behind:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
               Button b = sender as Button;

                if (b != null && b.Tag != null)
                {
                      Type pageType = Type.GetType(b.Tag.ToString());


                       if (pageType != null && rootFrame.CurrentSourcePageType != pageType)
                       {

                            rootFrame.Navigate(pageType);
                       }
                 }   
}
```

BasicPage1 and BasicPage2 are the pages I want to navigate to, inside the MainPage.

Comment: thanx man, but any way in silverlight? it will be very helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

If your main page has enough free space for your "other page", you can try this:
Place another Frame in your main XAML and navigate your other page to that frame. Your main remains visible AND active.

I do that already on bigger screens (Tablets) and know the pitfalls.
Do not use the navigation helper for your other page, because you will not navigate back rather then send other "other pages" to that frame. Or remove last backstack entry after navigation.

```
secondFrame.Navigate(pageType, frames);
if (secondFrame.BackStackDepth > 0)
   secondFrame.BackStack.RemoveAt(secondFrame.BackStackDepth - 1);
```